# Where to declare application scope variables on marionettejs I

Tags: marionette, yeoman-generator

I am using marionettejs yeoman generator
https://github.com/mrichard/generator-marionette
what's the best way to declare global variables like application root path and API endpoint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare them right on the app itself, or create a Util module or something.  There are numerous ways to do it.